# Is a php file able to request a tls certificate from the web browser?

Tags: php, tls1.2, mtls

I would like to ask if something like index.php is able to request a TLS certificate from the web browser.

If $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is On, then $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'] is not always containing a value.

I would like to ask, if the php file could ask the web browser for a Certificate.
Or does php depend on the web server / htaccess for the certificate stuff?

Comment: The rules of a client certificate are done in the web server. The PHP script can only check if there is a client certificate, control the values and that's all. TLS 1.3 doesn't allow client certificate.

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Restrict Apache to only allow access using SSL for some directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/429634/restrict-apache-to-only-allow-access-using-ssl-for-some-directories)

Comment: Is it not to possible to return a header or status code which asks for a client certificate?
From my viewpoint an answer like No, it is not possible - is acceptable.
Lets wait a few more days. Maybe someone else is having an idea.

Comment: @matjung in the past, I was looking for something like that, but I've never found. Only apache/nginx (others web server) seems to be able to deal with client certificat.